# No vehicles in Team Death Match?

Tags: battlefield-3

Are the vehicles just available in certain game types then? I've never played BF before and it's keeping me busy until 11/8. I only like TDM as I'm not much for objective capturing and I have yet to ever see one. What game types are they included in then?

Comment: Waiting for 11/8...classic!

Comment: @DarkShiva 11/8 was a giant let-down. BF3, not so much. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vehicles are available in the following modes:

- Rush
- Conquest
- Squad Deathmatch

whereas in Squad Deathmatch the only vehicle is the IFV (Infantry Fighting Vehicle). 
The other two game modes do not have this limitation.

Team Deathmatch and Squad Rush are infantry only.